# Interacting With Java Applet

Tags: java, .net, applet

Does anyone know if it is possible to interact with a java applet via .net?

Edit: I was able to use the UI Automation framework to locate the java applet, and from there use OCR to read data and simulate mouse/keyboard input into the applet.

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "interact". What is the problem that has led you to the proposed solution; i.e., "interacting with a Java applet via .NET"? There may well be a much better path to take...

Comment: Assuming the data isn't generated within the applet itself (i.e., on the client), does the applet talk to the server using a proprietary protocol or does it communicate via HTTP or some other common network protocol? What kind of data is this?

Comment: It communicates via a custom protocol, so I'm assuming that I'll need to caputer my data via OCR.  What I'm trying to figure out is the best way to interact with the applet.  I can't just do a type of macro since what I do and enter needs to change based on the data on each screen that I go through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may well be able to do it using accessibility APIs, which are designed to let screen-readers and so on interact with programs. Have a look at:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_UI_Automation

Comment: The UI automation framework appears unable to see inside the java applet.